# How much space should filters take on left side of page

Tags: filter, page-layout

I am designing a web interface where we have filters on left side and search results on remaining page. How much page's space should left filters take? Any percentage?

Comment: Hello @ammu. Unfortunately, there's no right or wrong answer to this, and will depend largely on a number of factors, like device width, how extensive your filters are, how much data is displayed in the results, etc. You'll ultimately just have to mock it up and see how it looks with your specific data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

300px is a good choice. Depending on the font-size and letter-spacing, you may need slightly more or less.

> A width between 20% and 40% is usually the best choice for a single sidebar and if you're going to use more than one sidebar, I suggest you don't exceed a total width of 50% (20% + 20% and 15% + 35%, for example).
>
> For a single sidebar, you can also utilize the Golden Ratio approach, where the width of the sidebar is around 38% of the main content area's width. You can find more information about Golden Ratio in Jarel Remick's The Golden Ratio in Web Design article at Nettuts+.
>
> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/anatomy-of-a-perfect-sidebar-the-nuances-of-a-good-design--wp-32576

Comment: Do you have any support for this recommendation?

Comment: Nothing official, like you have already mentioned. Just a good starting point.

Comment: This may help https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/anatomy-of-a-perfect-sidebar-the-nuances-of-a-good-design--wp-32576